# Constraint logic challenge

Tags: math, logic, probability, brute-force

Imagine the following equations:

```
2x + 3y + 4z + 5q = 32
x + y + z + q = 8
```

All variables are integers and have some constraints like

```
0 <= x <= xMax
0 <= y <= yMax
0 <= z <= zMax
0 <= q <= qMax
```

I know this has multiple solutions. How would you pick **RANDOMLY** one of the solutions without using brute-force?

Comment: Could you elaborate on picking randomly? Do you mean pick a random number for x, y, z, q and test it?

Comment: That would be more the brute-force approach which is actually what I want  to avoid... what I mean is to get a different solution each time... @Henrik yes, sorry about that... fixed

Comment: Well... you'll have to find all the solutions and then pick one randomly...

Comment: and how would you generate all the solutions?

Comment: Usually one will use an integer linear programming solver with a dummy variable as the optimization goal (to get all solutions). See for example http://www.aiexp.info/calculating-all-feasible-solutions-of-ilp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another approach to solve this. The original problem was to find a generic non-brute-force way to create an exam out of a pool of questions.

There were 4 types of questions

```
x, y, z, q
```

I had to randomly pick exactly 8 question

```
x + y + z + q = 8
```

Each type of question had a different score **AND** the total score of the picked questions had to be 32

```
2x + 3y + 4z + 5q = 32
```

If someone is interested you can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563596/subset-sum-solution-lenght)

Thanks for your help anyways :)